# Weird country_options_for_select in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I currently have my index.html.erb showing the following code.

```
<select name="country">  
<option>All</option>
<%= country_options_for_select('All') %>
</select>
```

But the result of the page becomes like this in the html source:

```
<select name="country">  
<option>All</option>
&lt;optionvalue=&quot;Afghanistan&quot;&gt;Afghanistan&lt;/option&gt;&lt;optionvalue=&quot;Aland
Islands&quot;&gt;AlandIslands&lt;/option&gt; ... 
</select>
```

It should be  instead of <option>

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Rails 2.3.14 to Rails 3.1.0, this works:

```
<%= country_options_for_select.html_safe %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using select_tag instead. It looks a bit cleaner.

```
<%= select_tag "name", country_options_for_select() %>
```

The reason the country options are showing up incorrectly is because you are passing 'All' to it. It doesn't need an argument there in your case. Only if you wanted a certain option selected by default.

For example,

```
<%= select_tag "name", country_options_for_select('Chile') %>
```

More info on it's use here: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/country_options_for_select

Comment: Hmm, doesn't work. The result is still <select id="country" name="country">&lt;option value=&quot;Afghanistan&quot;&gt;Afghanistan&lt;/option&gt;
&lt;option value=&quot;Aland Islands&quot;&gt;Aland Islands&lt;/option&gt;

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for, Thank you! unbelievable there's so few info regarding this two helpers together! Thanks again!